How to resize faces while one edge stays rooted/level?
I'm trying to extend these faces then shrink them, but keep them level to the "floor." I've only been able to shrink them from the face's center, then I need to manually level them (imprecisely).

This seems really simple, but I haven't been able to find a way around this. I want to be able to resize, but lock the bottom edges down, looking like this:

But without having to move them down myself (and getting it inexactly perpendicular).

For this, you'll be using the 3D cursor to set an explicit pivot point for your transformations.
By having the 3D cursor, therefore the pivot point in the same plane as the edges want to lock, the scaling operation will not move them out of that plane.
First you need to set the pivot point as the 3D cursor:

Then, you'll place the cursor in the plane you want to lock. Make a selection in the plane you want. You'll most likely want to make sure that the cursor remains centered relative to your mesh

Now, when performing the scale, the bottoms of the faces will stay in the same plane


(I took the liberty to creatively interpret how you got to the shape before scaling down, but the way I did it I had to change the pivot point and orientation, which would have to be set back to '3D Cursor' afterwards)

The I Inset operator has a 'Depth' parameter, so one approach when creating the new faces in the first place, (If your vault has no bottom face) would be to use 'Depth', with 'Boundary' switched off, so as not to inset from the bottom edges:

... which would also work in asymmetrical situations, where scaling would be uneven, and might provide more intuitive numerical entries, if you need precision.
